# How can changing the Hostname with Webmin Networking Configuration break a VPS network connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, webmin

I have a VPS with Contabo and Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I tried to change the hostname to `server.mydomain.com` by using the Network Configuration. I navigated to Network Configuration/Hostname and DNS Client. I changed the hostname and left everything as it was, saved it and applied the configuration. After the next reboot, the network stopped working and I couldn't connect to the VPS. I connected using VNC and the VPS couldn't connect with the outside world:

> Network is unreachable

Any ideas why this could happen?